# AutoIT WinWaitActive issue

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have a C# application with windows forms, using which I need to automate the opening of a file using an in-house software( mySoftware). I have the following code as below. My understanding is that WinWaitActive() should wait until I click on the in-house software window (mySoftwareWindow) and make it active, before the code moves on to the next line and opens the specified xml file (line 6 in code below). Instead whats happening is that the next line of code runs even before I can make the in-house software active, thus running the Open button (line 6 in code below) on the current active window, which in this case is the C# application form. What do you think is going wrong here? Thanks!

```
 aut = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class();
 aut.WinWaitActive("mySoftwareWindow", "", 1);
 aut.WinMenuSelectItem("mySoftwareWindow", "", "&File", "&Open", "", "", "", "", "", "");
 aut.Send("C:\\test.xml", 0);
 //click the Open button
 aut.Send("!o", 0);
 aut.Send("{ENTER}", 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is *very* short, 1 second isn't enough.  Make time-outs at least 10 times the worst case, go for at least 20 here.  *And* be sure to check the function return value, there's no point to continue if it returned failure.